# Parsing and writing a json variables boolean with file-system

Tags: javascript, json, fs

How would a parse a json variable then change it with the file-system node.js module like this
Json

```
{
   "fname": "node_module",
   "module": false,
   "files": {
        
   }
}
```

Javascript

```
const f = require("fs");
const ft = require("../structure.json");

function e() {
    let ftr = ft.folders;
    let ftmr = ftr.module;
    if(ftmr) {
        
    }
}

window.onload(e);
```

so far I have it reading the `module` variable, but don't know how I can check for it being false and how to change it with file-system.

How would go on about this, please and thank you!

Comment: Could you include the code you've written so far please?

Comment: @David784 const f = require("fs");
const ft = require("../structure.json");

function e() {
    let ftr = ft.folders;
    let ftmr = ftr.modules;
    if(ftmr) {
        
    }
}

window.onload(e);

Comment: @SNOOT you should be able to edit your question to add the code there; do you see an `edit` option under your question on the left? That would be better than in a comment, since you can format it properly as a code block, as you did with your JSON

Comment: @SNOOT If you are running in the browser (I see the `window` object), there is no access to the `fs` module.

Comment: @David784 yes I know about "edit"

Comment: What do you want to change `ft.module` to?  `if (ftmr) { /* here if true */ } else { /* here if false */ }`

Comment: @OldGeezer Yes I just want to change ```ftmr``` to false if it is true and true if false

Comment: @SNOOT SImply: `ftmr = !ftmr;`